# Print in google script using add-ons or Google extensions

Tags: google-apps-script

I started working on Google Script.

I wonder if there is some way to print in google script( be it text or google sheet data ) when a cell event is generated on the Google sheet.

Any suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `DriveApp` to create a new file (for example, a PDF) in your drive that has the desired data.

Comment: Do you mean print as in use a printer or print as in keep a changelog saved in a google sheet?

Comment: I mean print file using the printer.  Let us say I have a file on google drive, can I print that using google script.

Comment: It would be technically possible, but you would need to use webhooks and an API that accepts them, such as Google Print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Script cannot use system functions such as the print dialogue.

Comment: what about using some print add-ons. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Before proceeding further make sure you have added google cloud supporting printer to google account for printing because of security reasons services like print is not supported by google script**

- Open Google Drive.

  1. Right-click to make open Google Sheet.
  2. Add some rows.
  3. Click on **Tools** menu and select **Script editor** option.
  4. Select **File**  menu from script editor and then select **project properties** option.
  5. Note down the **Project key** (Deprecated)  and **Script_id** from **info** tab.
  6. Select Resources > Libraries.
  7. Add key `MswhXl8fVhTFUH_Q3UOJbXvxhMjh3Sh48` to **add library box**. Select latest  version from list and set **identifier** `OAuth2`.
- Open Google Cloud Console.

  1. To open Google Cloud Console follow this link  Google Cloud Console link, there in left navigation section you will find a credentials link.
  2. Click on **Credentials link**  >  **Create Credentials**. A popup will appear. From there select `OAuth Client Id` option.
  3. Under Application Type select Web Application. Set some name to Application. 
     In authorised script origins url box  paste below link. 
     `https://apis.google.com`

     In authorized redirected url box paste below link.
     `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT_ID}/usercallback`
  4. SCRIPT_ID is from project properties.
  5. Save the details.
  6. Note down Client_id and Client_secret for future use.
- Script.

Paste Below code in script window.

```
function showURL() {
  var cpService = getCloudPrintService();
  if (!cpService.hasAccess()) {
    console.log(cpService.getAuthorizationUrl());
  }
}

function getCloudPrintService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('print')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId('CLIENT_ID’)
    .setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET')
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudprint')
    .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var isAuthorized = getCloudPrintService().handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('You can now use Google Cloud Print from Apps Script.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Cloud Print Error: Access Denied');
  }
}
```

**getPrinterList** this method will check list of linked printer to account and return printer ID, NAME and DESCRIPTION

```
function getPrinterList() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/search', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getContentText();
  var printers = JSON.parse(response).printers;
  for (var p in printers) {
    Logger.log("%s %s %s", printers[p].id, printers[p].name, printers[p].description);
  }
}
```

- Last step.

  1. In script window select  Select Function  from toolbar and select showURL function and run code.
  2. Hit CMD + ENTER  to open logs. Copy the url from logs and paste in browser.
  3. Follow the direction and allow permissions for printer.

**Run below method with required parameters to add print job to cloud printer.**

```
function printGoogleDocument(docID, printerID, docName) {
  var ticket = {
    version: "1.0",
    print: {
      color: {
        type: "STANDARD_COLOR",
        vendor_id: "Color"
      },
      duplex: {
        type: "NO_DUPLEX"
      }
    }
  };

  var payload = {
    "printerid" : printerID,
    "title"     : docName,
    "content"   : DriveApp.getFileById(docID).getBlob(),
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "ticket"    : JSON.stringify(ticket)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit', {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + getCloudPrintService().getAccessToken()
    },
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  });

  response = JSON.parse(response);

  if (response.success) {
    Logger.log("%s", response.message);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error Code: %s %s", response.errorCode, response.message);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

If you face any error , kindly leave a reply.

Comment: This is a poorly formatted answer. I would recommend starting it with an overview (e.g. "here are the services we will set up, and the general idea"), and ensuring all of your code is properly formatted.

Comment: Poorly formatted answer. Kindly brief me about formatting.

Comment: @FaustoR. if you find it correct answer then accept the answer or need some more explanation then comment. Thanks

Comment: @shakir bhatt, I cannot accept the answer because I didn't ask the question. I did vote your answer as useful already, thanks again

Comment: Thank you! I used your solutions at that time and after many attempts it worked perfectly.